# Problem with replacing tick marks on the x axis using bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to graph this bar graph using `plt.bar` . This is my code

```
x_axis = np.arange(0,len(drug_name))
tick_locations = []
for x in x_axis:
    tick_locations.append(x)

plt.bar(x_axis, total_tp_per_drug, facecolor = "orangered", alpha = 0.75, align = "center") 
plt.xticks(tick_locations, drug_name)
plt.show()
```

Everything is perfect except for when I'm trying to replace the tick marks on the x axis with the drug name labels it's not doing it.  Can someone help me?

This is what's in `drug_name`

[image]

and this is the output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drug names are there, in your bar chart, but the default orientation is horizontal, so they're overlapping and unreadable. Try rotating the labels:

```
plt.xticks(tick_locations, drug_name, rotation=90)
```

(`rotation=45` would put them at an angle and might make them more readable)